# dropping a range of rows in a pandas data frame creates a key error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several different data frames, that I need to drop certain rows from.  Each data frame has the same sequence of rows but located in different areas

```
 Summary Results Report  Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1    Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3
0                DEM President         NaN         NaN           NaN        NaN
1                   Vote For 1         NaN         NaN           NaN        NaN
2                          NaN         NaN  Ballots By           NaN   Election
3                        TOTAL         NaN         NaN  Early Voting        NaN
4                          NaN         NaN        Mail           NaN        Day
5                   Tom Steyer         NaN         0 0             0          0
6                  Andrew Yang         NaN         0 0             0          0
7              John K. Delaney         NaN         0 0             0          0
8                  Cory Booker         NaN         0 0             0          0
9         Michael R. Bloomberg         NaN         4 1             1          2
10               Julian Castro         NaN         0 0             0          0
11            Elizabeth Warren         NaN         1 0             1          0
12         Marianne Williamson         NaN         0 0             0          0
13               Deval Patrick         NaN         0 0             0          0
14                 Robby Wells         NaN         0 0             0          0
15               Amy Klobuchar         NaN         3 1             2          0
16               Tulsi Gabbard         NaN         0 0             0          0
17              Michael Bennet         NaN         0 0             0          0
18              Bernie Sanders         NaN         4 0             1          3
19              Pete Buttigieg         NaN         0 0             0          0
20             Joseph R. Biden        21.0           0             3         18
21  Roque "Rocky" De La Fuente         NaN         0 0             0          0
22            Total Votes Cast        33.0           2             8         23
```

```
 Summary Results Report  Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2    Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5
0                  DEM US Senator         NaN         NaN         NaN           NaN        NaN         NaN
1                      Vote For 1         NaN         NaN         NaN           NaN        NaN         NaN
2                             NaN         NaN         NaN  Ballots By           NaN   Election         NaN
3                           TOTAL         NaN         NaN         NaN  Early Voting        NaN         NaN
4                             NaN         NaN         NaN        Mail           NaN        Day         NaN
5         Jack Daniel Foster, Jr.         4.0         NaN           0             0          4         NaN
6                 Mary (MJ) Hegar         4.0         NaN           1             3          0         NaN
7               Amanda K. Edwards         4.0         NaN           1             1          2         NaN
8                    D. R. Hunter         1.0         NaN           0             0          1         NaN
9                  Michael Cooper         3.0         NaN           0             0          3         NaN
10                     Chris Bell         1.0         NaN           0             0          1         NaN
11                     Royce West         3.0         NaN           0             0          3         NaN
12      Cristina Tzintzun Ramirez         5.0         NaN           0             3          2         NaN
13             Victor Hugo Harris         1.0         NaN           0             0          1         NaN
14                 Sema Hernandez         1.0         NaN           0             0          1         NaN
15                Adrian Ocegueda         0.0         NaN           0             0          0         NaN
16            Annie "Mama" Garcia         3.0         NaN           0             1          2         NaN
17            Total Votes Cast 30         NaN         NaN           2             8         20         NaN
18  DEM US Representative, Dist 1         NaN         NaN         NaN           NaN        NaN         NaN
19                     Vote For 1         NaN         NaN         NaN           NaN        NaN         NaN
20                            NaN         NaN         NaN  Ballots By           NaN   Election         NaN
21                          TOTAL         NaN         NaN         NaN  Early Voting        NaN         NaN
22                            NaN         NaN         NaN        Mail           NaN        Day         NaN
23                Hank Gilbert 26         NaN         NaN           1             6         19         NaN
24            Total Votes Cast 26         NaN         NaN           1             6         19         NaN
```

What I want to remove is the row that contains `Vote for 1` in the first column, as well as the following 3 rows.  The problem is that they can show in multiple areas, and in occasion multiple times (such as the second data frame).  What I have seems to be working, in the aspect that it removes the required rows, however, at the end, it will give me a `key error` which tells me that it is re-looping through without any data.

```
for x in range(len(df)):
        if 'Vote For 1' in str(df.iloc[:,0][x]):
            y = x+3
            df = df.drop(df.loc[x:y].index)
            df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
            df.index.name=None
            print(df)
```

the code produces the following output:

```
           Summary Results Report  Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5
0                  DEM US Senator         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN
1         Jack Daniel Foster, Jr.         4.0         NaN          0          0          4         NaN
2                 Mary (MJ) Hegar         4.0         NaN          1          3          0         NaN
3               Amanda K. Edwards         4.0         NaN          1          1          2         NaN
4                    D. R. Hunter         1.0         NaN          0          0          1         NaN
5                  Michael Cooper         3.0         NaN          0          0          3         NaN
6                      Chris Bell         1.0         NaN          0          0          1         NaN
7                      Royce West         3.0         NaN          0          0          3         NaN
8       Cristina Tzintzun Ramirez         5.0         NaN          0          3          2         NaN
9              Victor Hugo Harris         1.0         NaN          0          0          1         NaN
10                 Sema Hernandez         1.0         NaN          0          0          1         NaN
11                Adrian Ocegueda         0.0         NaN          0          0          0         NaN
12            Annie "Mama" Garcia         3.0         NaN          0          1          2         NaN
13            Total Votes Cast 30         NaN         NaN          2          8         20         NaN
14  DEM US Representative, Dist 1         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN
15                Hank Gilbert 26         NaN         NaN          1          6         19         NaN
16            Total Votes Cast 26         NaN         NaN          1          6         19         NaN
```

It errors out at the end with `KeyError: 17`.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

####EDIT####
I just wanted to give an update on the code that finally solved my problem.  I know that it is probably a little robust, but it does work.

```
remove_strings=['Vote For 1','TOTAL']
    remove_strings_list = df.index[df['Summary Results Report'].isin(remove_strings)].tolist()
    df = df.drop(df.index[remove_strings_list])
```

Comment: Can't `str(df.iloc[:,0][x])` be replaced with `df.iloc[x, 0]`? And also `df.loc[x:y].index` should probably be using `iloc`? btw I think your problem is that you are resetting your index inside the loop. I would suggest you don't alter your `df` in the loop but rather use the loop to create a list of indexes to drop and then drop them all at once only after your loop. Finally, should you be looping at all? You can almost certainly do this without a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what your column names are, but is the summary column contains the names and the few names you want to remove, this should work. Else you may have to change the column name accordingly.

```
strings_to_remove = ['Vote for 1', 'Total', 'NaN']
df[~df.summary.isin(strings_to_remove)]
```